# jQuery .load from external URL images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to load content from another page with jQuery load.
On that other page, the images are referenced as `/image/test.jpg` instead of `http://www.example.com/image/test.jpg` so it's not working.

How can I fix this?

```js
jQuery('#ext-desc').load('http://www.joyetech.com/product/ego-one-mega-vt-atomizer/ #container');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id ="ext-desc"></div>
```

Comment: You'd have to walk through every `img` tag and fix the URL. The only alternative is the `<base>` tag but that's awful, as it changes the URL base for all resources in your document

Comment: @Pekka웃 your answer is telling me I have to do it manually, I'm looking to do it programmatically

Comment: I mean walk through every `img` tag programmatically. `jQuery('#ext-desc img').each()...`